# Can I run multiple React programs from bash and view them on the web?

Tags: reactjs, macos, command-line, project

I would like to go back and forth between two React.js projects in Bash and view them on the web while programming them. Would localhost be able to view them both?

I haven't tried to yarn start them both, I am only asking. I am on a 2009 Macbook version 10.11.6.

Listening localhost/3000

Comment: why not? just use a diferent port for each one

Answer (score 3):

**You can run the two projects in different ports** (example: run one project on port 3000, and another on port 8000).  You can modify `package.json` under your project root directory to change the port number.
Below is an example of a `package.json` for running the project on port 8000.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": “PORT=8000 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run them on two separate ports.

As long as the servers are listening on different ports, they will be completely independent.